# Create React App - How to mock globally your own component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mocking

I have a component that I would like to mock for my test, which exists in **src/components/shared/DebouncedInput.js** and it looks like this:

```
import { useState, useCallback } from 'react'
import debounce from 'lodash.debounce'

const useDebounce = (callback, delay) => {
  const debouncedFn = useCallback(
    debounce((...args) => callback(...args), delay),
    [delay] // will recreate if delay changes
  );
  console.log('debouncedFn', debouncedFn);
  return debouncedFn;
};

function DebouncedInput(props) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(props.value);
  const debouncedSave = useDebounce(
    (nextValue) => props.onChange(nextValue),
    props.delay
  );

  const handleChange = (nextValue) => {
    setValue(nextValue);
    debouncedSave(nextValue);
  };

  return props.renderProps({ onInputChange: handleChange, value });
};

export default DebouncedInput;
```

I also have mocks for third party libraries in **src/**mocks**** folder.
Mocks for them work fine in my tests, but I am not sure where to put a mock for my own component **DebouncedInput** that I would like to mock so that it is globally available to my tests:

```
import React from "react";

function DebouncedInput(props) {
  const handleChange = (nextValue) => props.onChange(nextValue);

  return props.renderProps({ onInputChange: handleChange, value: props.value });
};

export default DebouncedInput;
```

I have put it in the **src/components/shared/**mocks**/DebouncedInput.js** folder, but that my test is still hitting the original implementation and not the mock. How should I implement this mock?

Comment: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-user-modules

Comment: so, I put the __mocks__ directory inside the shared folder, but my test is still hitting the original implementation and not the mock

Comment: Can you give a [mre]? What's the test that seems to be using the original implementation, are you calling jest.mock with the right path?

Comment: do I need to call jest.mock as well? I thought when the files are in the mocks folder that you don't need to do that

Comment: Per the link in my first comment (emphasis in original): *"When we require that module in our tests, explicitly calling `jest.mock('./moduleName')` is **required**."*

Comment: ah, don't know how I missed that, thanks!